# How to use showViewController?

Tags: ios, swift

I'm new to Xcode.I'm trying to figure out how to use showViewController.My question is how to call the UIViewController that to display ? via name or a identifier? And where can I find them ? In addition, the document says `The default implementation of this method calls the targetViewControllerForAction:sender: method to locate an object in the view controller hierarchy that overrides this method`,what does it mean? Should I call `targetViewControllerForAction:sender:`fist when using `showViewController`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

showViewController behavior basically depends on context you're app is in. 
But calling it is really simple. All you need is reference to your UIViewController object(or it's subclass).
You can do it in couple of different ways:

- If you're using Storyboards, give your storyboard view controller identifier, and use API call: UIStoryboard(name, bundle).instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier(identifier). This gives you UIViewController that you should pass as an argument to showViewController. You could find information about API here: https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIStoryboard_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010909-CH1-SW6
- Also, you could get your UIVIewController instance directly constructing it using proper initializer.

So: not worry about this `targetViewController` method, just get your object (initialize it via constructor or get it from storyboard), and pass it to show method.

In case you have further questions - feel free to ask.

Comment: I set bundle to nil now and it works nicely, when should I set it to some other value? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Nil is the same as if you would use NSBundle.mainBundle() which is main bundle of the application. You rarely need multiple bundles in your application(if you create one, and have storyboard you want to reference in it, you have to construct this bundle and give it as an argument to UIStoryboard initializer). You can find when to use multiple bundles here: [multiple_bundles](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/LoadingCode/Tasks/Componentizing.html)